# toggle KineticJs layer broken after rebuilding stage

Tags: javascript, angularjs, kineticjs

I have a canvas created with KineticJs Stage.  on this stage I have three layers.  One is the background and is always on.  The other two are overlays and the visibility is toggled by a checkbox.  Any time the parent div of this stage resizes I redraw the entire stage to keep my layout correct.  Here are the two situations where my toggling works:
1.  before resize and redraw.
2.  If I don't toggle it at all before the redraw.

Here is where it does not work:
1.  Toggle layer on then off.  Resize canvas to trigger redraw.  Then try and toggle back on.  In this case the visible attribute gets set to true when I call show() but the layer does not actually show up.

Stepping through the code I can not find any difference in the layer during any of the above scenarios.  I did however notice that the index of each layer gets incremented each time it is rebuilt even though I have instantiated new instances of the stage and every layer each time I rebuild.

Can anybody tell me why the index increments even though everything has been destroyed and why the layer is not showing up?  I was thinking zindex but this never seems to change and should be showing up.

here is what I do before every rebuild:

```
stage = new $window.Kinetic.Stage({
                container: 'canvas',
                x: 0,
                y: 0,
                width: parent.clientWidth,
                height: parent.clientHeight
            });
            var layer = new $window.Kinetic.Layer();
            erosionLayer = new $window.Kinetic.Layer({
                visible: scope.erosionVisible
            });
```

Here is where I toggle it:

```
 scope.$watch('erosionVisible', function(val) {
            if (!erosionLayer) return;

            var showErosion = false;

            if (!scope.erosionVisible) {
                showErosion = false;
            } else if (scope.erosionVisible) {
                showErosion = true;
            }

            if (showErosion) {
                erosionLayer.show();

            } else {
                erosionLayer.hide();
            }
        });
```

FYI, This is in an angularJs directive.

Answer (score 0):

fixed the issue.  for some reason I need to call draw on the layer when toggling if the stage has been rebuilt.